# Solution to complex differential equation $f'(z)=\frac{h(z)}{z^2+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I'm trying to solve a problem in complex analysis: Q 4E of the 2012 IB mathematical Tripos paper 4 section I. This is the link to the question:
https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/pastpapers/files/2012/PaperIB_4.pdf

$Let \; h:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic with $h(i) \neq h(-i)$.

Does there exist a holomorphic function $f$ defined in $|z|<1$ for which $f'(z)=\frac{h(z)}{z^2+1}$ ?

Does there exist a holomorphic function $f$ defined in $|z|>1$ for which $f'(z)=\frac{h(z)}{z^2+1}$ ?

I'm not sure how to even begin solving this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\gamma$ be a curve contained in $|z|<1$. It is easy to see that $\frac{h(z)}{z^2+1}$ is holomorphic in $\text{int}(\gamma)$, and thus by Cauchy's theorem
$$\oint_\gamma \frac{h(z)}{z^2+1}dz=0$$
Since this is true for every closed curve, $\frac{h(z)}{z^2+1}$ has a primivite $f$ inside the open unit disc (by the fundamental theorem of line integrals), and $f$ is holomorphic

Now, let $\gamma$ be a curve contained in $|z|>1$ encircling the origin. By the residue theorem,
$$\oint_\gamma\frac{h(z)}{z^2+1}dz=2\pi i\left(\text{Res}_{z=i}\frac{h(z)}{z^2+1}+\text{Res}_{z=-i}\frac{h(z)}{z^2+1}\right)$$

Since $\frac{h(z)}{z^2+1}=h(z)\frac{1}{(z+i)(z-i)}$, the two residues are $\frac{h(i)}{2i}, \frac{h(-i)}{-2i}$. Thus:
$$\oint_\gamma\frac{h(z)}{z^2+1}dz=\pi (h(i)-h(-i))\neq 0$$
Thus, by the fundamental theorem for line integrals, $\frac{h(z)}{z^2+1}$ does not have a primitive there.

Comment: Thank you for your help @caffeine!